# How to use an editor for build definition's input?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, build-definition

I am developing an a plugin that definitions build definitions. I have an option where you can add files. That option should be project specific and so data shouldn't persist between projects. I am using a fieldEditor to get the input values.

The problem I am having is that it persists the option values between different projects.

This is what I have in plugin.xml for the option

```
<option
      browseType="file"
      category="test.category.applications"
      fieldEditor="com.test.FieldEditor"
      command="${value}"
      id="test.applicationFiles"
      name="%option.app.files.name"
      valueType="string">
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're yusing field editors I guess you are also using IPreferenceStore to save the user preferences.

If so, then you have to change the scope content. You're probably using INSTANCE scope now:

```
IScopeContext context = InstanceScope.INSTANCE;
```

and you should be using project-wide preference scope instead:

```
IProject handle = ...
IScopeContext context = new ProjectScope(handle);
```

Comment: After getting the context, how do i set it for current instance?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking for. You don't want it to set to INSTANCE as INSTANCE serves as platform-wide scope. What you need is project-wide scope, represented by aforementioned ProjectScope. After getting the context, just create a preference store and use it as usual: `ScopedPreferenceStore scopedPreferenceStore = new ScopedPreferenceStore(projectScope, Activator.getDefault()
                .getBundle().getSymbolicName());`

Comment: I am trying to add an option that uses FieldEditor. The issue is that if I add a parameter for one project, I can see it in the settings of other project. In the init function :  public boolean init(IOption option, String extraArgument,
   String preferenceName, final Composite parent) {
     init(preferenceName, option.getName());  
     this.currOption = option;
     createControl(parent);
     return true; }       The curroption has the text which contains setting from other project.

Comment: After you edited the question: could you elaborate a bit on what exactly are you trying to achieve and why are you using a CDT extension? So you want to define some C/C++ toolchain?

Comment: I am trying to make a toolchain which has various tools that provides settings for building. The particular tool I asked you about, makes an executable (.nv). This executable requires some input files as parameters and this option I asked you about is used to add those files.